# Introducing errors by flipping bits

Tags: c, code-injection, bit

I have a character array in C into which I want to introduce errors by flipping some bits.

How can I flip bits and introduce errors?

Comment: Use `XOR 1` on each bit that you want to flip.

Answer (score 2):

You can flip bits using the xor operator:

```
x = x ^ mask;
x ^= mask; // Same functionality as above.
```

For example, if `mask` is `1`, the least significant bit is flipped. You can create any desired mask by bit-shifting the 1: `mask = 1 << k;` where `k` is the number of bits to shift.

Answer (score 1):

For distributing the errors, use a random number generator. `rand()` / `srand()` should suffice if this is for test purposes.

To flip a bit you can use the bit shifting and bitwise xor operators.

```
unsigned char flip(unsigned char c, int bit) {
    return c ^ (1 << bit);
}
```

You can also flip more than one bit by using a bitmask other than `(1 << bit)`, which has just one bit set:

```
unsigned char flip(unsigned char c, unsigned char mask) {
    return c ^ (1 << mask);
}

// flip bits 0 and 3 (00001001 = 0x09)
flip(c, 0x09);
```